# cant find where is failing the procedure

Tags: mysql

I spent an hour looking at the code but I can not find where it is failing

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS equipos$$
    CREATE PROCEDURE equipos(IN nom varchar, IN loc varchar, IN usu varchar
, IN pass varchar, OUT mensaje varchar, OUT nombreOut varchar)
    BEGIN
    select @var:=count(*) from usuario where usu=usuario.usuario;
    if(@var=0) THEN
        INSERT INTO `usuario`(`usuario`, `contraseña`) VALUES (usu,MD5(pass));
        select @id:=usuario.idUsuario from usuario WHERE usuario.usuario=usu;
        INSERT INTO `equipo`(`nombre`, `localidad`, `idUsuario`) VALUES (nom,loc,@id);
        SET mensaje="";
        Set nombreOut=nom;
    else
    SET mensaje="ya existe ese usuario";
    END IF;
    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

give me this error

```
something mistaken in your sintax near ' IN loc varchar, IN usu varchar, IN pass varchar, OUT mensaje varchar, OUT nombr' in line 1
```

Comment: MySQL does not give this kind of error message text: "something mistaken in your sintax near" ;)

Comment: i know i rewrote in english

Comment: Solution given should work for you. For closure, you can mark it accepted answer. Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a varchar, you have to specify its maximum length. Like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE equipos(IN nom varchar(255), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the maximum length of the variable when mentioning `VARCHAR` datatype

```
CREATE PROCEDURE equipos(IN nom varchar(64), ...
```